# Link to all the document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a requirement to upload a file from a document library from another list.

My requirement is like:

I have a document library called 'Documents' to upload specific files(pdf and word). I have a discussion board called 'Latest News', in which I need to upload the files from 'Documents' as attachment. I have tried with Lookup, but that's not a ideal solution, if I have large number of documents. I need to link to the 'documents library' from my discussionboard 'Latest News'.

I am not sure how to proceed. Please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create column of type **Hyper link or picture** and link the document by putting url and display text.

[image]

If user clicks on code snippets link, file will get downloaded.

Comment: Hi Rishabh, Thanks for the quick reply. But by adding Hyper link or picture we need to copy and paste the url. That's not expected by user. I am not sure your thought is like this.. please help